# Vuejs: is using "props" a secure way to pass data between components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

**Question:**

Is using *"props"* in Vue.js a secure way of passing data between components? For example, passing username and password data between 2 or more components.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by secure? Everything on the client is exposed, so I would argue that storing password in properties is insecure.

Comment: Does using props reveal the data being passed to the client? Eg. passing data containing the user's password to another component.

Comment: I don't believe it is any less secure then storing the password in a native variable and passing that around. However you are still persisting the plaintext variable in the client's memory. If you have to pass something around I would use the password to fetch a token from an auth server, then pass that token around.

Comment: @ezennnn Having user credentials in the frontend *always* reveals them. Regardless of whether you pass them between components.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, they are. They are just a reflection of the origin. 
Passing data through props doesn't have any security issues.