# Should you prioritize passing props over API requests in your web app architecture?

Tags: vue.js, architecture, frontend, vue-router

**Background**

I'm building a Vue App using the Composition API. I have a backend where I retrieve data to load pages and components.

**Question**

In terms of architecture, should I prioritize passing props along multiple components ***or*** making new requests to load data when loading new pages?

*Passing Props Example:*

1. I have a v-for that renders smaller preview components.
2. When clicked, a new page loads and passes data from that component to the new page.
3. This new page renders the data in full

The alternative would be to ***only pass the id of the data*** as a route param, make a request and pull the data from the DB to render the page.

*I'm curious what the best practice is in terms of app architecture?*

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of just passing the id of the data (as a route param or prop). But instead of requesting the data to the API, you could use the store. Check if the data is present (and not outdated) in your store and if no valid data is found in the store, you can request it from your backend database.

[Link to Vuex store guide](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

Comment: I'm using Pinia in my app but that makes sense. I read somewhere online that it is not secure to pass all the data through props. So for security I'm guessing it might be good to just make more API calls? It just seems quite redundant.

Comment: You should consider the fact that everything in the client is accessible to the user. Check this post: [vuejs is using props a secure way to pass data between components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478752/vuejs-is-using-props-a-secure-way-to-pass-data-between-components).